# Flutter-create listview with multi textEditingController

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create multi input in list view with dynamic total item count . I use list of textcontroller but when I input a data all controller show with same value.

this my controller :

```
int totalItem = 15;

List<TextEditingController> _color = List.filled(15, TextEditingController());
List<TextEditingController> _brand = List.filled(15, TextEditingController());
```

implement at textfield :

```
         Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _color[index],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Color",
              labelText: "Color",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _brand[index],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Brand",
              labelText: "Brand",
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

When run the app text controller show with same value.
Please help me to solve this problem?

Complete code : https://github.com/gunartha/listview_with_multi_input

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because of the way the `List.filled` constructor works. [In the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) it mentions:

> Creates a list of the given length with `fill` at each position.

Implying that `fill` (in this case your `TextEditingController`) is only initialized once, and a reference to this same controller is then put in each index. As a result, all color fields are controlled by (a reference to) the same Controller instance, and the same goes for brands.

To resolve this, you'll need to use a different way to initialize your list of controllers. A simple loop would suffice, but you may also be able to come up with a more elegant solution.

Here's some example code to initialize the lists in a loop in `initState`:

```dart
  List<TextEditingController> _color = [];
  List<TextEditingController> _brand = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalItem; i++) {
      _color.add(TextEditingController());
      _brand.add(TextEditingController());
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Which works as expected on my machine.