# define variable name in dart made of a random number

Tags: dart

Is it possible in Dart to define a variable like this

```
int randNum = Random().nextInt(1000000) + 1;
TextEditingController controller + randNum;
```

So I want to be able to generate a varialbe name in this example of TextEditingController with a name for example `controller` + a random generated number so it should be something like this `TextEditingController controller6435` for example.

Comment: You cannot do this. Dart source names must be known at compile-time, so you cannot create one at runtime. You would have no way to *reference* that variable in the program.

To create a name at (or before) compile-time, you need to look into source-generation.

Comment: Why would you want this?  What actual problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: I have a ListView and inside this ListView I want to define unique names for each TextField Widget - TextEditingController, because if it has the same controller it will repeat my value inside the TextField Widget to all my TextField Widgets inside my ListView. I hope you understand.

Comment: You don't need random variable names, just some way to refer to the appropriate `TextEditingContoller`.  Store them in a `List` instead.

Comment: FYI, this is an example of [the X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/).

Comment: You are right, but you pushed me in the right dirrection and I found this question and I was able to some my X problem :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67935892/flutter-create-listview-with-multi-texteditingcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it's possible to have a dynamic variable name in dart.
But you could use a Map to do what you want:

```
Map<int, TextEditingController> controllers = {};
int randNum = Random().nextInt(1000000) + 1;
controllers[randNum] = TextEditingController();
```

This way you have a map that associates random ints with controllers.

Comment: I get `The name 'TextEditingController' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`

Comment: You are probably just missing the import. Make sure you have `import 'package:flutter/material.dart'` at the top of your file.

Comment: Also, Jeremy's code has some bugs with the types, the following should work:
```dart
Map<String, TextEditingController> controllers = {};
String randNum = (Random().nextInt(1000000) + 1).toString();
controllers["controller" + randNum] = TextEditingController();
```